# AWS ACM certificate created with terraform can't be validated, domain doesn't have valid NS (?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53, aws-acm, aws-acm-certificate

I have a domain generated and managed with AWS Route53. This domain has been manually created but the rest of the infrastructure is created using terraform in different regions to avoid the initial FARGATE CPU limit.

The infrastructure is updated using a GitHub action.

I am trying to create `dev` environment in `eu-north-1` but `terraform apply` failes after 1H+ of `**maws_acm_certifi***e_validation.default: Still creating... [***h***5m0s elapsed]` with this error:

```
 **m│ **m**mError: **mwaiting for ACM Certifi***e (arn:aws:acm:***:***:certifi***e***7a0***bccb-0c***7-***776-ab9***-***e670b6a38f***) to be issued: timeout while waiting for state to become 'ISSUED' (last state: 'PENDING_VALIDATION', timeout: ***h***5m0s)
**m│ 
**m│   with aws_acm_certifi***e_validation.default,
**m│   on aws-acm.tf line ***, in resource "aws_acm_certifi***e_validation" "default":
**m│   ***: resource "aws_acm_certifi***e_validation" "default" **m{
**m│ 
**m╵
**m╷
**m│ **m**mError: **mcreating ELBv*** Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:***:***:loadbalancer***app***-legacy-dev-alb***7***e5baa5dab6d3e6): UnsupportedCertifi***e: The certifi***e 'arn:aws:acm:***:***:certifi***e***7a0***bccb-0c***7-***776-ab9***-***e670b6a38f***' must have a fully-qualified domain name, a supported signature, and a supported key size.
**m│    status code: ***00, request id: 3***f5a0e9-c***ac-***fd3-aed0-60ba39***0590***
**m│ 
**m│   with aws_lb_listener.https_listener,
**m│   on aws-alb.tf line 70, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "https_listener":
**m│   70: resource "aws_lb_listener" "https_listener" **m{
```

I think the second error is just related to the first one because the certificate isn't correctly in issued status. It's a little bit hard to read but the error says `waiting for ACM Certificate to be issued: timeout while waiting for state to become 'ISSUED' (last state: 'PENDING_VALIDATION', timeout: ...)`.

This is part of terraform code related to the certificate:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "default" {
  domain_name               = var.root_domain_name
  subject_alternative_names = ["*.${var.root_domain_name}"]
  validation_method         = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "default" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.default.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = local.validation_record_fqdns
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "default" {
  name    = "${local.resource_prefix}.${var.root_domain_name}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  zone_id = var.route53_record_zone_id
  records = [aws_lb.main.dns_name]
  ttl     = 60

  depends_on = [aws_lb.main]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_validation" {
  name    = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_name
  type    = "CNAME"
  zone_id = var.route53_record_zone_id
  records = [tolist(aws_acm_certificate.default.domain_validation_options)[0].resource_record_value]
  ttl     = 300

  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.default]
}
```

I tried to add the CNAME record manually and via AWS interface via "Create records in Route 53" button too but the certificate is still in pending.

[image]

This is the record entry in Route 53:

[image]

Is there a way to trigger again this verification and fix the problem?

**UPDATE:**

Tried like in the terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation) but same result.

I am starting to think there's a DNS problem with my domain. The domain should have been registered directly in AWS (I didn't do it) and when I use tools like [this](https://network-tools.webwiz.net/nslookup.htm) (or [this](https://www.broadbandsearch.net/nslookup)) online nslookup and input the domain I am working with I can't get the NS, instead I get them for another domain that my company owns.

Is there something wrong with the domain instead?

Domain info:

[image]

Comment: Your Route53 hosted zone isn't setup as the actual DNS server for your domain yet. You have to configure the NS records at your domain name registrar where the domain name has been registered to point to your Route 53 hosted zone.

Comment: Hello, the domain has been purchased directly from AWS. Is there a way to check if Route53 is correctly setup? I added an image of the domain details. The same NS are entered as NS records in the Route53 hosted zone. Can it be that the domain has suspended after 15 days from it's creation? I don't have access to the email that has been used for the registration and probably my colleagues didn't confirm the domain yet. It was working before and the 15 days to confirm it ended last week when it started to not work.

Comment: Yes it sounds like you've figured it out. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-click-email-link.html

Comment: Yes, it was that. When the domain has been disabled, I was destroying and re-creating the whole infrastructure so I thought it was something related to what I was doing. Now I confirmed the domain and it started to work again and the nslookup has the name servers again, thank!

Answer (score -2):

Requests for ACM certificates time out if they are not validated within 72 hours. To correct this condition, open the console, find the record for the certificate, click the checkbox for it, choose Actions, and choose Delete. Then choose Actions and Request a certificate to begin again. For more information, see DNS validation or Email validation. We recommend that you use DNS validation if possible.

Please check this link from the [AWS Knowledge center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-pending-validation/)

If the hosted zone is destroyed and re-provisioned, new name server records are associated with the new hosted zone. However, the domain name might still have the previous name server records associated with it.

If AWS Route 53 is used as the domain name registrar, head to Route 53 > Registered domains > ${your-domain-name} > Add or edit name servers and add the newly associated name server records from the hosted zone to the registered domain.

Comment: Hello, the certificate has been destroyed and created again many times but the result is always the same.